# How to create view hierarchy programmatically?

Tags: ios, ios4, ipad

I usually create my view hierarchy's in IB but this time I need to do it in my code. Basically I already have my custom view but I want it to be contained inside a UINavigationController. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to nest it in a Navigation controller you should use :

```
   UIViewController * myViewController = [[GameController alloc] init];
    myViewController.view = yourCustumeView;//if you are trying to add a UIView
   UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                          initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
   [navigationController  release];
   [myViewController  release];
```

Good luck

**EDIT**
add this code (before the release):

```
    navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;//change it to rightBarButtonItem if the button is on the right.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create several ViewControllers then you can allocate them in code and then in order to show them just push it like this:

```
RegistrationViewController * regView= [[RegistrationViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:regView animated:YES];
```

Comment: Hi, he was asking about adding his view to a UINavigationController. fix your answer and i will remove my down vote.